# Open the BootstrapDialog edit user form with some error if a user had not filled some field value. In laravel 5.4

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5.4, bootstrap-dialog

I am using BootstrapDialog to open a edit user form. It opens perfectly.

In my list page when a user click on **edit** button, it will go to controller and and fetch that user information, and at the end it will show the Dialog Box which have a form and update button. 
When he/she click on update button it will call update function of its controller and validate all field and revert back to the dialog box if some error is there. Other wise close the dialog box and show a success message.

My question is when someone left blank to a field and it validate in controller, but it does not able to show the dialog box anymore. How can I show error message to the user in that Dialog box.
I am using laravel 5.4.

**Edit Button**

```
<a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary edit_user_" 
   id="edit_user_<?php echo $v->id; ?>" 
   data-title="{{ $v->name }}" 
   href="edit-user/<?php echo $v->id; ?>">
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" title="Edit" ></i> 
   Edit
</a>
```

Js

```
$('.edit_user_').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        BootstrapDialog.show({
            title: $(this).attr('data-title') +"'s  "+ 'Information',
            message: $('<div></div>').load(url),
            closable: true,
            closeByBackdrop: false,
            closeByKeyboard: false,
            draggable: true,
            buttons: [{
                icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-save',
                label: 'Update',
                action: function(dialogRef) {
                    $('form').submit();
                },
                cssClass: 'btn-primary'
            }]
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Controller

```
public function updateSelectedUser(Request $request){
        $id = $request->input('hId');
        $oldImage = $request->input('oldImage');

        $validator = $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$id,
            'name' => 'required|min:5',
            'userimage' => 'required|image'
        ]);
        //$path = Storage::putFile('userimages',$request['userimage']);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::back()->with(array('error_code'=>1, 'uId'=>$id));
        } else {
            echo 'Validation Done';
        }
    }
```

And my edit.blade.php template

```html
<div class='row'>

 <div class='col-md-12'>
  <div class="box box-primary">
   <div class="box-header with-border">
     <h3 class="box-title">Edit User</h3>
   </div>
    <!-- form start -->
    <form class="" role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" files="true" action="<?php echo asset('regUser/update');?>" >
     {{ csrf_field() }}
     <input type="hidden" name="hId" value="{{ $info->id }}">
     <div class="box-body">      
      <!-- Name -->
      <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
       <label for="name" >Name</label>        
       <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name', $info->name)}}" placeholder="Your Name" required >
       @if ($errors->has('name'))
        <span class="help-block">
         <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
        </span>
       @endif       
      </div>
      
      <!-- Email -->
      <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
       <label for="email" >Email</label>        
       <input id="email" type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email', $info->email)}}" placeholder="Your Email" required >
       @if ($errors->has('email'))
        <span class="help-block">
         <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
        </span>
       @endif       
      </div>
      
      <!-- Profile Pic-->
      <div class="row">
      <div class='col-md-6'>
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="userimage" >Image</label>
        <input id="userimage" type="file"  name="userimage" required>
        @if ($errors->has('userimage'))
         <span class="help-block">
          <strong>{{ $errors->first('userimage') }}</strong>
         </span>
        @endif
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class='col-md-6'>
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="userimage" >Old Image</label>
        <img class="img-circle" src="{{asset('public/storage/'. $info->userimage )}}" alt="" style="height:50px;"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="oldImage" value="{{ $info->userimage }}">
       </div>
      </div>
      </div>

     </div>
      <!-- /.box-body -->
      
    {!! Form::close()  !!}
  </div>
 </div><!-- /.col -->

</div><!-- /.row -->
```